# How to join string List Array On C#

Tags: c#

I have array of string from the DataTable, so i'm use this code to get list :

```
ListTid = string.Join(",", DtTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["NameColumn"].ToString()));
```

then i have result like this :

```
LIS1, LIST2, LIST3
```

How if i want result like this

```
'List1','List2','List3'
```

Comment: So you want `'`s in addition to `,`s between each element? What have you tried?

Comment: Please tell me you're not going to use this in an sql query. It smells like an sql injection vulnerability waiting to happen.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'm hopefully optimistic it's for a CSV write function.

Comment: i have list data on array =1,2,3,4 and want send to query parameter, like this
exec storedprocedure @parameter='1','2','3','4'

Comment: Yeah, that's probably vulnerable to sql injection. Look into a table-valued parameter.

Comment: so any other solution for this ?

Comment: Yes: Table-valued Parameters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can continue to use `String.Join`, just add the extra quotes at the end, like so:

```
ListTid = '\'' + String.Join("', '", DtTable.AsEnumerable().Select( r => r["NameColumn"].ToString() ) ) + '\'';
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the quotes in your select code, like this:

```
ListTid = string.Join(",", DtTable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => string.Format("'{0}'",Convert.ToString(r["NameColumn"])));
```

Note that I have changed your code to use `Convert.ToString` since it can safely handle nulls, whereas `ToString` will throw an exception.

Comment: Careful, this approach results in extra strong concatenation operations which means extra memory usage.

Comment: thist result
'''TED00000'''',''''TED00001'''',''''TED00002'''',''''TED00003''''